# Disable the button based on control validation which inside ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

plunkr link

https://plnkr.co/edit/vuktW1bWSNIoV43Qp8DC?p=preview

```
 <form name="myForm">
    <div ng-repeat ="ndc in NDCarray">
    <div class="col-sm-4 type7" style="font-size:14px;">
        <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">NDC9</div>

  <label>Number:
    <input type="number"  ng-model="ndc.value"
           min="0" max="99" name="{{'input_'+$index}}" required>
 </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$dirty && myForm.input.$error.required">
      Required!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.number">
      Not valid number!</span>
  </div>
  <tt>value = {{example.value}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm['input_{{$index}}'].$valid = {{myForm['input_'+$index].$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm['input_{{$index}}'].$error = {{myForm['input_'+$index].$error}}</tt><br/>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 type7 " style="font-size:14px;">
        <div style="padding-top:20px; display:block"> 
            <span class="red" id="delete" ng-class="{'disabled' : 'true'}" ng-click="NDCdelete($index)">Delete</span> &nbsp; 
            <span>Cancel </span> &nbsp;  
            <span id="addRow" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="NDCadd()">Add </span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
 <button>Save</button>
   </form>
```

we can enter the value in number and click add, it will create new textbox with same option (delete,cancel,add).  That textbox has some validation

1. Required
2. Min and Max range
   If i create 4 text-boxes dynamically by clicking add and changing the value of any textbox causes  validation failed means , i want to disable the save button which is outside of ng-repeat.

if any textbox failed in validation need to disable the save button.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
<button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid">Save</button>
```

As far as I understand your question this is what you are trying to achieve?